# SIP based door entry and phone system

Tags: networking, voip, sip, power-over-ethernet

For a residential home, we've allowed for a door entry system, where we'd like to the following:

1. Push button at door entry panel calls all intercom stations (handsets) - audio only
2. From any intercom station, you can "buzz in" someone through the front door (release electronic latch)
3. From any intercom station, you can call another station (e.g. ground floor to upper floors). Ideally, option to have a station auto-answer and be on speaker (so you can "shout" upstairs from a ground floor intercom.
4. In order to save on wall junk, we'd like to use the same intercom stations / handsets to make regular phone calls

We've wired CAT5e point-to-point (daisy chained).

**Question 1**

I've identified [a Stentofon TCIS-3 door entry panel](https://intercom.ringuk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2012/05/1008111030_TCIS-3_Turbine_Compact_IP_Standard-3.pdf) that works as a SIP phone, but I'm a unclear how to get power to all the intercom stations, and how to connect it all to the PSTN telephone too.

**Question 2**

I know the Stentofon TCIS-3 can be powered via PoE, but can most SIP phones too? And can such devices be powered when the cat5e is point-point (PoE or injecting power - see diagram below)?

Here is diagram of my proposed setup:[image]

thanks,
Ash

P.S. Here's a [more extensive guide](http://www.techring.co.za/downloads/manuals/A100K11194_Turbine_Stations_Configuration_Manual2.pdf) to the door entry system